# Selenium ChromeDriver C# - How to send a shortcut browser

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

How can I send a Chrome shortcut with Selenium ? 
I mean shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> which has nothing to do with WebElements. I read a lot of similar questions there, but none of the suggested solutions work for me.

Let's say I want to open a new tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) on the browser, I tried all the following code without success:

1. The "standard" way :

   ```
   IWebElement body = myDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
   body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
   ```
2. The action way :

   ```
   Actions action = new Actions(myDriver);
   action.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t").Build().Perform();
   ```
3. The ChromeDriver way 1 :

   ```
   if(myDriver is ChromeDriver)
   {
       ChromeDriver chromeDriver = myDriver as ChromeDriver;
       chromeDriver.Keyboard.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
   }
   ```
4. The ChromeDriver way 2 :

   ```
   ChromeDriver chromeDriver = myDriver as ChromeDriver;
   chromeDriver.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.Control);
   chromeDriver.Keyboard.PressKey("t");
   chromeDriver.Keyboard.ReleaseKey(Keys.Control);
   chromeDriver.Keyboard.ReleaseKey("t");
   ```

Notice that the first way i mentionned worked for me with other WebDriver than Chrome.
I use :

- Selenium 3.0.1
- ChromeDriver 2.27.440174

And my driver's initialization is really basic :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
this.myDriver = new ChromeDriver(/* my path */, options);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem to be `Chromium` [issue](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=175909&view=revision). You cannot use keys combinations with `chromedriver`, but you still can use `JavaScript` as alternative:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = myDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open()"); // Open new browser tab like `CTRL + t` do
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative :) I was focused on send Key events but your solution worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=667387) currently prevents chrome from reacting to shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> sent by selenium.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using key combinations with Actions just fine. I have been using this code example for years and it works with Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

```
public void SelectAll()
{
    (new Actions(yourDriverInstance)).SendKeys(Keys.Control).SendKeys("a").Perform();            
}
```

Am I missing something???